# Joomla 2.5 disabled module after successful login

Tags: joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5.

I would like to disabled a module only when my user has successfully login to it.

in another words, I would like to display a module only to the users who are not login.

Anyone please kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($user->guest) {
    // If user is not loged in
    // <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position" />
} else {
    // User is loged in
    // <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position" />
}
```

Comment: Where you are loading login module?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for guest user access. By default all users that are not logged in are assigned to the public user group when they visit a Joomla site. You need to add a guest user group that can see everything Public can see, but can be excluded from what registered users can see.

This a quick tutorial on how to accomplish that task - http://www.cmsmind.com/joomla-1-7-5-easy-steps-to-create-guest-only-access-to-menus-and-modules/

It was written for 1.7 but the process is the same.